# Facebook Registration Can't parse fields attribute. Is it a JSON array or CSV list error in IE

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, plugins, registration

I am trying to use the facebook registration plugin. I have it working in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE I receive the 'Can't parse fields attribute. Is it a JSON array or CSV list?'

I've found though if I take off the last custom field is fine. I tried rearranging the field order, but whenever I have over 10 fields I always get the error in IE.

My code is as follows:

```
iframe id='ifFacebookRego' style='margin-top: 50px' src='https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration.php?
                        client_id=******&
                        redirect_uri=******?method=facebook&fields=[
                        { "name":"name" },
                        { "name":"first_name" },
                        { "name":"last_name" },
                        { "name":"email" },
                        { "name":"nrl_team",     "description":"NRL Team Interest",      "type": "select",   "options":{ "1":"Broncos",
                                                                                                                        "2":"Bulldogs",
                                                                                                                        "8":"Cowboys",
                                                                                                                        "11":"Dragons",
                                                                                                                        "9":"Eels",
                                                                                                                        "7":"Knights",
                                                                                                                        "10":"Panthers",
                                                                                                                        "12":"Rabbitohs",
                                                                                                                        "3": "Raiders",
                                                                                                                        "13": "Roosters",
                                                                                                                        "5":"Sea Eagles",
                                                                                                                        "4":"Sharks",
                                                                                                                        "6":"Storm",
                                                                                                                        "16":"Titans",
                                                                                                                        "15":"West Tigers",
                                                                                                                        "14":"Warriors",
                                                                                                                        "17":"Gold Coast Jnr.",
                                                                                                                        "18":"St. George Jnr.",
                                                                                                                        "19":"Parramatta Jnr.",
                                                                                                                        "20":"South Sydney Jnr.",
                                                                                                                        "21":"Manly Warringah Jnr.",
                                                                                                                        "22":"Canterbury-Banksrtown Jnr." } },
                        { "name":"phone",      "description":"Australian Mobile",             "type":"text" },
                        { "name":"cbHealthNutrition",   "description": "Health  Nutrition",        "type":"checkbox" },
                        { "name":"cbEntertainingSolutions", "description": "Entertaining Solutions",        "type":"checkbox" },
                        { "name":"cbEverydayIdeas", "description": "Easy Everyday Ideas",        "type":"checkbox" },
                        { "name":"cbHealthForFamily",   "description": "Health for my Family",        "type":"checkbox" },
                        { "name":"gender" }]'
                scrolling="auto"
                frameborder="no"
                style="border:none"
                allowTransparency="true"
                width="360"
                height="650">
            /iframe>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to this issue. Because the fields json is parse in to the iframe in the source url, the url was too long. I shortened the names of my fields and all works.